# Removing \N (NULL character) from a file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I export MySQL database into CSV, and MySQL places `\N` instead of `NULL` fields. I want to remove the `\N` from the output, and since the database file is large, I need to do it in place.

I tried `sed`

```
sed -i 's/\N//g' file.csv
```

but apparently, `sed` does not recognise `\N`, as it removes `N` only.

Comment: is that a literal backslash+uppercase-N, or is `\N` meant as code for some control character or such? E.g. `\n` is often used to signify the newline. If it's a literal backslash+N, try `\\N`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed needs special characters to be prepended with`\`. So to remove \N:

```
sed -i 's/\\N//g' file.csv
```